# How to do url rewriting for zeus server?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, zeus

My site is in zeus server. Now i need to redirect my site to secure site using https. I found that url rewriting code different for zeus server. How do i use url rewriting code? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a `Zeus TrafficScript rule` for achieving this. I suggest you read the manual at http://knowledgehub.zeus.com/media/4.1/trafficscript_manual.pdf to understand more about this.

What you're most likely to use is the `http.changeSite()` method like this to send the user to SSL version of your site

```
if( http.getHostHeader() == "www.mysite.com" ) {
http.changeSite( "https://www.mysite.com" );
}
```